# Do employees of Stack Overflow use Stack Overflow to build Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

"Use" as in: ask questions on Stack Overflow to find answers to development related questions.

Comment: Why don't you look at their profiles? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded

Comment: Wouldnt that mean there shouldn't be a Stack Overflow as Stack Overflow would have been needed to build Stack Overflow?

Comment: `i have big site. i migrated to SSL and now style sheet is not loading any more and it is giving error. Plz help is urgent!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!`

Comment: @Pekka웃 `This is an off-topic question` for meta !!!

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176011/sql-to-determine-minimum-sequential-days-of-access)

Comment: No, SO's dev team are all Yahoo! Answers fanatics. We've tried several times to convince them to start using SO, but we failed. Apparently they don't appreciate the level of noise here...

Comment: @Yannis I could imagine why. lately there is a lot of crap posted, answers such as. why isn't my stylesheet working (forgot to add it in the head)

Comment: Do [LOGO problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo) count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, occasionally staff *do* ask questions to help build SO with.

Here are a few of [Jeff Atwood♦'s questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=questions&sort=votes):

> [Calculate relative time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)
>
> [Calculate age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age)
>
> [SQL to determine minimum sequential days of access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176011/sql-to-determine-minimum-sequential-days-of-access)
>
> [Determining "Owner" of Text Edited by Multiple Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424220/determining-owner-of-text-edited-by-multiple-users)

Comment: There's also the classic [frame buster buster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed) :)

Comment: @TimPost Actually it's a frame buster buster *buster* `:p`

Comment: You know, buster3 wouldn't be a horrible display name. I'm highly considering it.